# Call onclick event of some other tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I need to call the onclick event of one tag when some other hyperlink is clicked.

```
<div class="a"><a href=".." onclick=".?." >   // tag1
</div>
<span class="b"><a href=".." onclick="echo('hi');" >   // tag2
</span>
```

Thus whenever onclick event of tag1 gets executed, it should do nothing but call the onclick event of tag 2. How do i do this? (Sorry, new to Javascript).

Comment: The question is why would you want to do this? This will lead to user confusion over what was/wasn't clicked.

Comment: It would be better to extract both things into a function or three; having JS code in tags is not the best way.

Comment: you can call the onclick method of first tag within echo() method body?

Comment: call the function from the hyperling onclick function

Comment: This is for some testing/debugging purpose, i agree this would have lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("b")[0].children[0].click();
}
```

That should do it.

You can also use (i fixed your HTML as well. Missing `</a>`):

```
<div class="a"><a href=".." onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('b')[0].children[0].click();">Link Text</a></div> <!-- Tag 1 -->
<span class="b"><a href=".." onclick="alert('Hi')">Link 2 Text</a></span> <!-- Tag 2 -->
```

Comment: does [0] signify represent the first sub tag under the parent tag ?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Well, it does if you talking about `.children[0]`

Comment: You can also directly call element.onclick();

Comment: Great ! Thanks @Shawn31313 .One last question, would this work if span was defined before div ?

Comment: Looking at the second code, shouldn't `document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].children[0].click();` have 'b' instead of 'a'. We want to call b's onclick event right ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Yes it should. Sorry. When I switched them, I must of forgot about changing that. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a javascript function. And attach it to onClick handler.

```
<div class="a"><a href=".." onclick="someName()" >   // tag1
</div>
<span class="b"><a href=".." onclick="someName()" >   // tag2
</span>

<script>
  function someName(){
       alert("Hi");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your question you want to call the same functions onclick of tag 1 and tag 2, so to put it simple you can assign same onclick function to both tags.

```
<div class="a"><a href=".." onclick="myFunction()" >   // tag1
</div>
<span class="b"><a href=".." onclick="myFunction()" >   // tag2
</span>
```

Or if you want to call it some other way like if there is some inline action provided on tag2 and you want to call it from tag 1 you can use:-

```
<div class="a"><a href=".." onclick="$('.b').click()" >   // tag1
</div>
<span class="b"><a href=".." onclick="echo('hi');" >   // tag2
</span>
```

Comment: -1. jQuery is not tagged. Questions without library tags should be answered without libraries.